# Is it possible to restore windows 2008 server to larger raid array?

Tags: windows-server-2008, raid, backup-restoration

**Warning**: I'm a developer not an administrator.

I have a Windows 2008 server that is providing Active Directory and some directory shares and it is running out of space.  Currently, it has three 250GB hard drives configured in raid (5?) to provide 500GB of usable storage.

- The motherboard provides RAID support and its configured to do so in the BIOS
- The disk management tool only shows one 500GB hard drive
- The server can boot from the RAID hard drives (they are the only hard drives)

The server is backed up nightly to a 1TB removable hard drive so tried the following.

- Swap the three 250GB drives for 1TB drives so there will be about 2TB of space.
- Boot from the install disk and restored from the previous nights backup

Now, I have a working server but its not using RAID.  In the disk management tool I can see all three hard drives and two of them are unallocated.

**EDIT**

I just realized that I didn't create a raid array with the new disks before doing the restore.  I just created a raid array and started the restore again.  Now the restore only sees one disk (it saw three last night).

Answer (score 1):

It wont auto grow onto new drives. You will need to take a bare metal image of your current system, install the new drives and create the new array, then bare metal restore onto that new array.

Comment: I noticed this.  I had to use the disk management tool to allocate the unallocated space.